# Split a string into an array using explode

Tags: php

```
$string_to_split = (1_house & flats);
$split_string = explode("_", $string_to_split);
```

As shown above I'm trying to split a string into an array
When I print `$split_string[0]` I get 1 of which it's correct according to my expectations but when I print `$split_string[1`] I get "house" not "house & flats"because that's what I expected.

Comment: Are yo missing the quote marks on that string?

Comment: Here I am getting this : https://eval.in/716139

Comment: check this https://eval.in/716148

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you put your String_to_split in quotes like "1_house and flats". Do not make use of the brackets to indicate a string.

Since your string is not in quotes, Php sees the & sign as an operator, that's why it won't give you the "house and flats", as you require.

Your syntax for the explode Function is OK. Wish you success.

Comment: My bad I made a mistake when writing this question. My string was on quote without brackets...the only problem was the & that is ignored thanks for your response